# How do I allow a user to trust and pin a self-signed SSL Certificate using AFNetworking in iOS

Tags: ios, ssl, afnetworking-2, pinning

I'm working on an iOS application that will be used by enterprises. Our app will be talking to a server that may be configured with a self-signed certificate generated by the company that has deployed our server software.

Our iOS application is using AFNetworking which allows for SSL Pinning. But I get the impression that this only pins SSL certificates that were included as part of the app bundle when it was created. It does not allow you to work with a certificate that the iOS device becomes aware of later.

I'm looking for a way for the customer to push out (perhaps via a profile) the self-signed cert so that our application can securely talk to the server. Is there a way? Or do I need to skip AFNetworking and use the Foundation classes directly.

I welcome any comments to help clarify this question as well.

UPDATE: For others who may have been confused as I was. While I understand pinning to be an important topic, I was confusing it with my first priority: removing support for invalid certificates from our prototype app. What I wanted was a way for a user to explicitly trust a self-signed cert. This is simple. Just add it as a profile to your iOS device. But I was also being tripped up by the fact that the self-signed certs we were using in development weren't quite right so iOS would not trust them. See http://blog.httpwatch.com/2013/12/12/five-tips-for-using-self-signed-ssl-certificates-with-ios/ on how to generate a "good" self-signed cert. Now that I have self-signed certs being trusted, I will follow up on how to use pinning.

Comment: Are you using AFNetworking 1 or 2?

Comment: I am using version 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, `AFSecurityPolicy` has a property [`pinnedCertificates`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/2.1.0/AFNetworking/AFSecurityPolicy.h#L52) which defaults to using any certificate in the app bundle if you use the [`policyWithPinningMode:`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/2.1.0/AFNetworking/AFSecurityPolicy.m#L213) factory method.

To use your own certificates, set this property to an NSArray containing the [`NSData`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html) representations of each user certificate:

```
AFSecurityPolicy *securityPolicy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeCertificate];
NSData *certificateData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile...
securityPolicy.pinnedCertificates = @[ certificateData ];
```

Comment: Thanks David for your response. We'll be testing this.

Comment: No trouble, let me know how you get on

Comment: It may be a week or two before we get to this. I'm going to mark your answer as correct. (The documentation certainly supports you. I had just missed that in my review of the documentation. Or I was looking at an older version of the docs.)

Comment: I know it wasn't possible with AFNetworking 1, but v2 is pretty flexible due to its excellent design. Interesting use-case you have too.

Comment: David, I'm just thinking that this shouldn't be that interesting of a use case. I was just investigating now (based on your answer) how to access an iOS profile. I thought I'd just email a certificate. Click on it. The user gets asked if they want to import as a profile. Then I thought I'd be able to ask the OS to give me the cert (as an NSData) and pass it to the pinnedCertificates property. But based on searching I've done, it's not possible to access the profiles. The best advice I've seen so far is this: https://devforums.apple.com/message/603203#603203